# JAXB Date Marshalling Issue

Tags: java, date, jaxb, timezone

I have a large web service that builds a response object, the relies on JAXB for marshalling it out to the final XML to be returned.  In that object I have a number of Date fields.  Some of the date fields must not have time zone information and some do (based on bizarre business rules).

In the code, which has not changed for years, for that dates that must not have TZ information we have a custom type adapter to do what we need.  For all the other fields we let JAXB take care of it for us: to marshal and unmarshal the Date to include the TZ information.

For every release of new builds of the service we have a custom regression system to ensure not one byte of the response changes from known good responses.  In our most recent build we have an issue that cropping up periodically where those dates where the TZ is expected, it's missing:

```
Old Value:2014-05-14T08:24:20.283-04:00
New Value:2014-05-14T08:24:20.283Z
```

And, the frustrating part, is when we run the test again for the failed request, the second time the test passes: meaning the TZ is back.  Very hard to debug when the bug is not reproducible on demand.

Nowhere in the code that I can find, and in all the dependencies is the system ever changing the JVM TimeZone, or the default format (Locale.setDefault) that I can find.

Has anybody every seen this type JAXB inconsistency with a Date?

We could write another custom adapter that forces the to/from marshalling to have the TZ... But I just don't understand why now, after years of use, suddenly decided to change on us.

UPDATE
Here is the new adapter.  Nothing extravigant.  But, Like I said, this issue happened before the addition of this adapter.  After it's addition, I've no idea if it's resolved yet... No time to test yet.

```
public class CustomDateTimeTZAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>{
    private static DateFormat getFormatter() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"); // <---------------- NOTE:  The "XXX" for Timezone is only JAVA 7+ supported!
    }
    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        try {
            return getFormatter().parse(v);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        if (v != null) {
            return getFormatter().format(v);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But the date-time string ending with 'Z' *does* contain a timezone - it is the same as +00:00 or -00:00. The strings you show are indeed different points in time, but if the value of the hour field is changed as well to the correct hour, then all is in order. - Please confirm/deny whether the "different" values are merely different in representation or actually different in value.

Comment: So you were unmarshalling TZ-holding dates to `Date`, like in `java.util.Date`? But that does not handle time zones. Consider posting your custom adapter. I'd actually blame the default TZ first, but it's hard to say without seeing your adapter code.

Comment: The data came from a MSSQL database through a MyBatis layer.  In teh database it's exactly "2014-05-14T08:24:20.283", but as you know, MSSQL does not support timezones.  The only thing saving us is the database, the web server, and the system that wrote to the database originally are all in Eastern Time (Standard or Savings depending on the time of year).  So it sounds to me like maybe I've been blaming JAXB, but there might be a MyBatis problem.  The big problem is that it's inconsistent.  I'll post my new adapter code, but it may not resolve it if MyBatis is to blame.

Comment: @lexicore, I am thinking along the same lines.  The Date is just a date (seconds from epoch or whatever).  So it's the conversion from Date to String when marshalling where the TZ was inaccurate.  The JVM TZ was no longer Eastern.  I just don't know how/where that would have happened.  I guess in my adapter I can catch it...